# getter is invoke before v-if in child slot component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I create a vue component that I want to do some logic and according the logic I want to render whatever in the slot.

```
<logic-component>
 <div>{{ data }}</div>
</logic-component>
```

the data is a getter:

```
 get data() { return … }
```

the data is getting from global store/service that if fulfilled when the logic-component is ready.

The component logic is looks like that:

```
<div v-if="logicIsReady"><slot></slot></div>
```

So by default `logicIsReady` set to false, but the getter is invoke before.

Now, by vue lifecycle I know that vue try to resolve the current component binding and after that is going for the children. but as you can see here is different.

How can I vue to render whatever in the slot only when the `v-if` is `true`?

There is something I can do in vue?

if I use v-if instead of the component it works, but this is not the way I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the `v-if` logic inside the child, but the parent will need to change its syntax and use the explicit [named slot form](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand):

```html
<logic-component>
  <template #default>
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
  </template>
</logic-component>
```

The default slot is actually a [named slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) with the name "default". By wrapping in an explicit `template`, the `logic-component` gets a chance to decide when to render it.